# SOQL Query Formulation Error

Tags: apex, soql

Hi I have a problem in formulation of query: project object is master of proj team. When employee start date is **12-7-2017** (which is in mid week- **Wednesday**) and end date is **30-12-2017**, i am not getting the record for project. If i keep the employee start date as **10-7-2017** (**Monday**). I am getting the record. And the comparison will always be start of monday and sunday dates as given below.

```
 SELECT Id, Name, project_type__c, Project_Start_Date__c,Project_End_Date__c FROM Project__c WHERE ID IN(SELECT Project__c From Proj_Team__c WHERE Employee__c = 'a010k000000x9yd' AND Emp_Start_Date__c <= 2017-07-10 AND Emp_End_Date__c >= 2017-07-16)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check on your condition.

I guess Your looking for the employee who's starting date is after 2017-07-10 or  equal to 2017-07-10. And Employee End date is before 2017-07-16  or equal to 2017-07-16.

```
SELECT Id, Name, project_type__c, Project_Start_Date__c,Project_End_Date__c FROM Project__c WHERE ID IN(SELECT Project__c From Proj_Team__c WHERE Employee__c = 'a010k000000x9yd' AND Emp_Start_Date__c >= 2017-07-10 AND Emp_End_Date__c <= 2017-07-16)
```

Comment: If you check the dates with the query still the query fails.

Comment: @EffatNaaz what error your getting ?